# xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path

Tags: python, qt

Whenever I start a python script that tries to access the keyboard, for example, with OpenCV's waitKey() method, I get the following error:

```
Qt: Failed to create XKB context!
Use QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT environmental variable to provide an additional search path, add ':' as separator to provide several search paths and/or make sure that XKB configuration data directory contains recent enough contents, to update please see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/ .
```

This error started to appear when I installed the keyboard library (or pynput, I am not quite sure) and persisted after I uninstalled them. I do not have QT installed. 
Also, neither OpenCV's waitKey nor the two installed libraries can detect any key events (I suspect this is connected), which was already the case before I got the error though.

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04.

How can I go about this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this recent issue was resolved here:
https://github.com/conda-forge/qt-feedstock/issues/104

I think the solution is

```sh
export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb
```

but I'm not an expert... somebody back me up here please.

Comment: on centos I had to use `QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/lib/kbd/keymaps/xkb`  but that's the same thing, only the path differs.